Maximum value of $2$ variable function $f(u,v)=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{uv}\right)^2}{\frac{1-u^2}{2u}+\frac{1-v^2}{2v}}$
Finding maximum value of

$\displaystyle f(a,b)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{b}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\cot a+\cot b}$, Where $a,b\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$

What I try : $\displaystyle \tan\frac{a}{2}=u,\tan\frac{b}{2}=v$
Then $\displaystyle \tan (a)=\frac{2\tan \frac{a}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{a}{2}}=\frac{2u}{1-u^2}$
And $\displaystyle \tan (b)=\frac{2v}{1-v^2}$
So $\displaystyle f(u,v)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{uv}\bigg)^2}{\frac{1-u^2}{2u}+\frac{1-v^2}{2v}}\;, u,v>0$
$\displaystyle f(u,v)=\frac{2uv(1-\sqrt{uv})^2}{(u+v)(1-uv)}$
How do I find maximum value of that function of $2$ variable, Please have a look on that , Thanks

The function $f(u,v)$ in your question is not the same as the one given in the title.

The function in the header blows up near $(0,0)$.   The function in the body is different

I have edited it.

$$\displaystyle f(a,b)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{b}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\cot a+\cot b}$$
$$\displaystyle f(a,b)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{b}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{a}{2}}{2\tan\frac{a}{2}}+\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{b}{2}}{2\tan\frac{b}{2}}}$$
$$\tan\frac{a}{2}=x,\tan\frac{b}{2}=y  \,||a,b \in(0,\frac\pi2)\implies x,y \in(0,1), \,xy\in(0,1)$$
$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{2xy(1-\sqrt{xy})^2}{(x+y)(1-xy)}$$
$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{2xy(1-\sqrt{xy})^2}{(x+y)(1-\sqrt{xy})(1+\sqrt{xy})}$$
$$\displaystyle f(x,y)=\frac{xy(1-\sqrt{xy})}{\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)(1+\sqrt{xy})}\tag1$$
$$\displaystyle f(x,y)\le\frac{\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)(1-\sqrt{xy})}{1+\sqrt{xy}}$$
$$ \,\sqrt{xy}=t\,||t \in (0,1)$$
$$\displaystyle f(t)\le\frac{t(1-t)}{1+t}\le 3-\left(t+1+\frac{2}{t+1}\right)\le 3-2\sqrt2\tag2$$
$$\boxed{f(x,y)\le 3-2\sqrt2}$$
$AM\ge GM$ at $(1)$ and $(2)$

You can substitute $s = (u+v)/2$ and $p =\sqrt{uv}$ and you get, using the sum-difference rule on the $(1-p^2)$ in the denominator:
$$f(u,v) = g(s,p) = \frac{p^2(1-p)}{s(1+p)}$$
The two variables are still $>0$, but AM-GM inequality implies $s \ge p$. The bigger is $s$, the smaller the function becomes, so that
$$ g(s,p) \le h(p)= \frac{p(1-p)}{(1+p)} $$
The maximum of $h(p)$ is found by imposing a null derivative:
$$ 0= h'(p) = \frac{(1+p)(1-2p)-p(1-p)}{(1+p)^2}$$
$$ 1-2p-p^2 = 0 $$
$$ (p+1)^2 =2$$
That is $p=-1+\sqrt{2}$ (it has to be positive). In this value we get
$$h(p)= \frac{(-1+\sqrt{2})(2-\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}} $$
$$ = \boxed{ 3-2\sqrt{2}} $$
The equality $g(s,p)=h(p)$ is verified whenever $u=v$. In your original formulation,the maximum is then reached for $a=b =45°$, which realizes $\tan(a/2)=\sqrt{2}-1$. This value makes me suspect a geometric proof is possible...

1. Question Copy to Refer to its Equations in the Solution
Finding maximum value of 

$$\displaystyle f(a,b)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{b}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\cot a+\cot b},\,\text{ Where }a,b\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\tag{Eq. 1.1}$$

2. Solution Steps
Notice that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$, that is that $f$ is symmetric under the transformation $a\to b$ and $b \to a$.  Therefore maxima and minima are suspected for $a=b$.  In that case, (which needs -and has- plot verification), then Equation 1.1 becomes very easy to solve:
$$\displaystyle f(a,a)=\frac{\bigg(1-\tan\frac{a}{2}\bigg)^2}{2 \cot a}$$ $$\tag{2.1}$$
In any case, the three-dimensional Desmos plot is the first place to start to arrive at a numerical partial solution.
3. Three Dimensional Desmos Plots
Let $a\to x$, $b \to y$ and $f \to z$ and then:
The maximum is graphed with:
$$z=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)}\right)^{2}}{\cot\left(x\right)+\cot\left(y\right)}$$
The numerical solution (as can be seen from the graph) is:
$$ z\approx 0.1715$$
The graph finding the maximum from Desmos is quoted below as:



It also has plotted $x=0$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to see the symmetry in the problem.
The settings are as follows:



From this additional Desmos plot, it is indeed possible to conclude that $a=b$ at the maximum, as suspected:



So now the numerical simulation can be done in terms of a function of one variable $f \to y$ and $a \to x$:
$$\displaystyle y=f(a,a)=\frac{\bigg(1-\tan\frac{a}{2}\bigg)^2}{2 \cot a}$$
$$
=\frac{\bigg(1-\tan\frac{x}{2}\bigg)^2}{2 \cot x}$$
$$\tag{Equation 2.1 Reference}$$
The quoted Desmos plots follow:

The following Equations were plotted:
$$
y=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)}\right)^{2}}{\cot\left(x\right)+\cot\left(x\right)}
$$
The maximum for $f(a,b)$ is then calculated as:
$$
y=0.17157=3-2\cdot\sqrt{2}
$$
Indeed from the Ubuntu Calculator application:



This occurs when $a=x=0.785$ and $b=x=0.785$ with:
$$
x=y=a=b=0.785
$$
being graphed.  Note that this two-dimensional plot is a Desmos graphing calculator within some numerical precision, that allows the maximum to be determined by sliding the clicked cursor along the curve.  It is much more accurate (but arrives at a similar value) than the three-dimensional plots.  Its settings were:



This approach should be helpful to compare with any symbolic answers to see if they arrive at the same result or not.  Or if not to troubleshoot why there is any discrepancy.  In some applications, these sorts of numerical methods are sufficient to arrive at an answer that is correct to the necessary precision.
Now additional steps can be taken to solve Equation 2.1 symbolically using trigonometric identities to hopefully identify a polynomial solution.  But in the meanwhile, this work is a very useful hint on how to fully resolve the problem symbolically (if necessary) or even as a stand-alone numerical solution it may be sufficient.
4. Symbolic Calculation of the Maximum Applying a=b for the Maximum of $f(a,b)_{maximum}=f(a,a)_{maximum}$ 
Start with the question:

$$\displaystyle f(a,b)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{b}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\cot a+\cot b},\,\text{ Where }a,b\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\tag{Eq. 1.1 Reference}$$

Next, because of the symmetry of $f(a,b)$ meaning that the gradient that points in the maximum direction of assent $\vec \nabla f(a,b)=\vec \nabla f(b,a)$, then set $b=a$ to arrive at:
$$\displaystyle f(a,a)=\frac{\bigg(1-\sqrt{\tan\frac{a}{2}\tan\frac{a}{2}}\bigg)^2}{\cot a+\cot a},\,\text{ Where }a\in\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$$
$$\tag{Eq. 4.2}$$
$$\displaystyle f(a,a)=\frac{\bigg(1-\tan\frac{a}{2}\bigg)^2}{2\cdot \cot a}$$
$$\tag{Eq. 4.3}$$
From the trigonometric identities at Clark University:

Thus
$$\displaystyle f(a,a)=\frac{\bigg(1-\frac{1-\cos a}{sin a}\bigg)^2}{2\cdot \frac{\cos a}{\sin a}}$$
$$=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(\sin a -\left(1-\cos a\right) \bigg)^2$$
$$=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)^2
$$
$$=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)\cdot \bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)
$$
$$=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(\sin a \cdot \bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)
+\cos a \cdot \bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)
\\ - 1 \cdot \bigg(\sin a+\cos a -1\bigg)
\bigg)
$$
$$=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(\sin a \cdot \sin a+\sin a \cdot \cos a -\sin a \cdot 1 \\
+\cos a \cdot \sin a+\cos a \cdot \cos a -\cos a \cdot 1\\
\\ -\sin a-\cos a +1\bigg)
$$
$$f(a,a)=\frac1{2 \cdot \sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(2+2\cdot \sin a \cdot \cos a -2\cdot \sin a 
-2\cdot \cos a\bigg)
$$
$$f(a,a)=\frac1{\sin a\cdot \cos a}
\bigg(1+\sin a \cdot \cos a - \sin a -\cos a\bigg)\\
=1+\frac1{\sin a\cdot \cos a}-\frac1{\cos a}-\frac1{\sin a}
$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 4.4}$$
Now take the derivative $\frac1{d\,a}f(a,a)=0$ to find maxima as follows:
$$\frac1{d\,a}f(a,a)=
\frac1{d\,a}\bigg(1+\frac1{\sin a\cdot \cos a}-\frac1{\cos a}-\frac1{\sin a}\bigg)
$$
$$\frac1{d\,a}f(a,a)=
\frac1{d\,a}\frac1{\sin a\cdot \cos a}
-\frac1{d\,a}\frac1{\cos a}-\frac1{d\,a}\frac1{\sin a}
=0$$
$$\tag{Eqs. 4.5}$$
Completing Equation 4.5 with the derivative set to zero should result in the maxima and minima across the domain.  Each of these is then compared to identify the global maximum.
Although these steps are not complete to the end, the necessary technique is clear enough to be helpful for finding the complete symbolic solution, which was already verified with numerical methods.
Indeed solving Equation 4.5 with Desmos 2-dimensional numerical methods with $a\to x$ and $b\to x$ and $f\to y$ results in a single maximum, with $x=a=b=\frac{\pi}{4}=0.785398163397$ as below (symbolically as well as numerically):

$$y=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{\cos\left(x\right)}-\frac{1}{\sin\ \left(x\right)}\right)=0$$
Applying the quotient rule, "If $y=\frac{u}{v}$ then $\frac{d\,y}{d\,x}=\frac{ 
 v \frac{d\,u}{d\,x} -u \frac{d\,v}{d\,x}
 }{v^2}$" and
$$y=\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)-\sin^2\left(x\right)}
{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}
-\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\left(\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}
+\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)^2}$$
$$y=
\frac1{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}
\left(
 \cos^2\left(x\right)-\sin^2\left(x\right)
-\sin^3\left(x\right)
+\cos^3\left(x\right)\right)$$
Dividing by $\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)$ yields quoted from  GeoGebra:

$$y=
\frac1{\left(\sin\left(x\right)\cdot\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}
\left(\cos x - \sin x\right)\cdot
\left(
 \cos\left(x\right)+\sin\left(x\right)
+\sin^2\left(x\right)
+\cos\left(x\right)\cdot\sin\left(x\right) 
+\cos^2\left(x\right)\right)$$

And now since $\cos \frac{\pi}{4}=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ then within the domain $x=a \in \bigg(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)$ there is an exact answer for $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ this can be symbolically substituted into Equation 4.5 referenced below:
$$f(a,a)=1+\frac1{\sin a\cdot \cos a}-\frac1{\cos a}-\frac1{\sin a}
$$
$$\tag{Referenced Eq. 4.4}$$
With $\sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$, and
$\cos \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ then
$$f(a=\frac{\pi}{4},a=\frac{\pi}{4})=
1+2-2\sqrt{2}=3-2\sqrt{2}$$
The numerical methods also identified this answer for the maximum of $f(a,b)$ occurs at:
$$\boxed{f(a=\frac{\pi}{4},b=\frac{\pi}{4})=
1+2-2\sqrt{2}=3-2\sqrt{2}}$$

Andrea Marino has already provided a good answer.
One can avoid using derivative.
We have $0\lt u\lt 1$ and $0\lt v\lt 1$.
By AM-GM inequality, we have $u+v\ge 2\sqrt{uv}$
which implies
$$\frac{1}{u+v}\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{uv}}$$
Using this, we have
$$\begin{align}f(u,v)&=\frac{2uv(1-\sqrt{uv})^2}{(u+v)(1-uv)}
\\\\&\le \frac{2uv(1-\sqrt{uv})^2}{2\sqrt{uv}(1-uv)}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{uv}(1-\sqrt{uv})^2}{(1-\sqrt{uv})(1+\sqrt{uv})}
\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{uv}(1-\sqrt{uv})}{1+\sqrt{uv}}
\\\\&=2-\sqrt{uv}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{uv}+1}
\\\\&=3-\bigg((\sqrt{uv}+1)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{uv}+1}\bigg)\tag1\end{align}$$
By AM-GM inequality, we have
$$(\sqrt{uv}+1)+\frac{2}{\sqrt{uv}+1}\ge 2\sqrt 2$$
So, from $(1)$, we can say that, for every $(u,v)$ satisfying $0\lt u\lt 1$ and $0\lt v\lt 1$, we have
$$f(u,v)\le 3-2\sqrt 2$$
The equality $f(u,v)=3-2\sqrt 2$ is attained when $(u,v)=(\sqrt 2-1,\sqrt 2-1)$.
Therefore, we can say that the maximum value of $f(u,v)$ where $0\lt u\lt 1$ and $0\lt v\lt 1$ is $\color{red}{3-2\sqrt 2}$.

We start from $\displaystyle f(u,v)=\frac{(1-\sqrt{uv})^2}{\frac{1-u^2}{2u}+\frac{1-v^2}{2v}}, u,v>0$ by substituting $uv=a^2$ where $a>0$. We further assume $a\ne 1$ for obvious reasons. Therefore, $\max_{u>0,v>0} f(u,v)=\max_{u>0,a>0} f\left(u,\frac{a^2}{u}\right)$ and we obtain
$$
f\left(u,\frac{a^2}{u}\right)
{
=
\frac{(1-a)^2}{\frac{1-u^2}{2u}+\frac{u^2-a^4}{2a^2u}}
=
\frac{(1-a)^2}{\frac{a^2-a^2u^2}{2a^2u}+\frac{u^2-a^4}{2a^2u}}
=
\frac{2a^2(1-a)^2u}{a^2-a^4+(1-a^2)u^2}
\\=
\frac{2a^2(1-a)^2}{1-a^2}\frac{u}{a^2+u^2}
=
\frac{2a^2(1-a)}{1+a}\frac{u}{a^2+u^2}.
}
$$
The last equality allows us to write
$$
\max_{a>0}
\max_{u>0}
f\left(u,\frac{a^2}{u}\right)
{
=
\max_{a>0}
\max_{u>0}
\frac{2a^2(1-a)}{1+a}\frac{u}{a^2+u^2}
=
\max_{a>0}
\frac{a(1-a)}{1+a}.
}
$$
The last maximum occurs at $a^*=\sqrt 2-1$. Therefore, the maximum of $f(u,v)$ occurs at $u=v=\sqrt2-1$ with a value of $3-2\sqrt 2$ $\blacksquare$

After simplications
$$f(u,v)=\frac{2\, u\, v \,\left(1-\sqrt{u\, v}\right)^2}{(u+v) \,(1-u\, v)}$$
If we use the symmetry $f(u,v)=f(v,u)$ the problem is simple. Since $u>0$
$$f(u,u)=\frac{(1-u)\, u}{1+u} \quad \implies \quad f'(u,u)=-\frac{u^2+2 u-1}{(u+1)^2}$$ which cancels et two points
$$u_\pm=-1\pm \sqrt 2$$
Even if $u_-$ could be discarded (since negative), looking at the second derivative
$$f''(u,u)=-\frac{4}{(1+u)^3}\quad \quad f''(u_-,u_-)=\sqrt 2\quad \quad f''(u_+,u_+)=-\sqrt 2$$ and then
$$f(u_+,u_+)=3-2 \sqrt{2}$$
Without using the symmetry
Computing the partial derivatives and taking out the denominator, we need to solve
$$-2 v^2 \left(\sqrt{u v}-1\right) \left(u^2 \left(\sqrt{u v}+v^2-1\right)-2 u v+\sqrt{u v}\right)=0 \tag 1$$
$$-2 u^2 \left(\sqrt{u v}-1\right) \left(u^2 v^2+v^2 \left(\sqrt{u v}-1\right)-2 u v+\sqrt{u v}\right)=0 \tag2$$
Computing $(1)$-$(2)$ we have
$$2 (u-v) (u+v) \left(\sqrt{u v}-1\right) \left(u v (u v-2)+\sqrt{u v}\right)=0 \tag 3$$ which is easy to solve  for the first terms.
For the last one, let $u v=x^2$ to face
$$(x-1) x \left(x^2+x-1\right)=0$$ This gives the possible relations between $u$ and  $v$;
Now, having all these relations, plug in $(1)$ or $(2)$ and use cases.
